# JQuery .before() add html block escape

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, append

I just want to add a html block using .before() fucntion of JQuery here is the block :

```
$buttonValue = '<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" '.$str .'>
                 <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
                 <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
                 <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal"></a>
                 <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
               </div>';
```

and here is the Script that I use it :

```
    $script  = "(function($){\n";
    $script  .= "$(document).ready(function(){\n";            
    $script  .= "$( \".prod-view\" ).before( \"$buttonValue\" );";
    $script .=      "});    \n";
    $script .=      "})(jQuery);" ;
```

I have already tried php addslashes() function, but with no luck

Comment: Try wrapping the value in $buttonValue in a $()

Comment: Why not write your JavaScript as actual JavaScript rather than a PHP string?

Comment: Please tell me what you trying to archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$buttonValue = '<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" '.$str .'><a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a><a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a><a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal"></a><a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a></div>';
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$script  = "(function($){\n";
    $script  .= "$(document).ready(function(){\n";            
    $script  .= "$( \".prod-view\" ).before( '$buttonValue' );";
    $script .=      "});    \n";
    $script .=      "})(jQuery);" ;
```

Differences from you code is make the html in single line, otherwise it make a js error. And then use semicolon in `.before()`

Comment: We can also use this code to eliminate the new line character  

`$string = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $code);`

Comment: Ya..sure...Anyway glad i could help you